# Railsのwhereで取得した結果をエスケープさせたくない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsでwhere文で取得したデータの中に、クエスチョンマークやクオーテーションマークがあった場合、エスケープされて

```
&amp;
```

等になっています。

viewで表示させる際は、ビュー内で.html_safeをして解決しましたが、
コントローラ内の処理（をdelayed_jobのjobに書き出したもの）で、直接取得したデータを使いたい場合に、どうすればいいかわかりません。

具体的には、取得したデータを、あるAPIを利用した検索ワードとして使いたいのですが、その際にエスケープする前の文字列を検索ワードとして使いたいのです。

```
@hoge_data = Hoge.where(neko: nil).order(created_at: :DESC).limit(10)

@hoge_data.each{|row|

  if row.nil?
    # データ空のときとりあえず何もしない
  else
    p row['title']
    p row['title'].class
    p row['title'].html_safe
    item = get_data_from_tako(row['title'])
  end
}
```

`p row['title'].html_safe` も　`p row['title']`も同じものが表示されます。
`p row['title'].class`はstringです。
item = get_data_from_tako(row['title'].html_safe)
にすると、

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `bytesize' for nil:NilClass>
```

が返ります。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

素直にRails/ActiveRecordを使っている範囲では、データベースから持ってきたデータが勝手にエスケープされるようなことはありません。

```
p row['title']
```

でエスケープされた状態で表示されたと言うことは、DBに保存しているデータが既にエスケープされた状態か、どこかで余計なエスケープをするように意図的に作り込んだかどちらかです。

なお、闇雲に`.html_safe`するのはやめましょう。